# ¿Es correcto declarar clases vacías en una jerarquía de clases?

Tags: poo, herencia, diseño

¿Es aceptable, desde el punto de vista de diseño orientado a objetos, tener una clase vacía en una jerarquía de clases solo para satisfacer un criterio semántico relacionado con el problema que se modela?

Ejemplo simple:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen tengo una clase `Electrodoméstico` con sus atributos y métodos, de la cual hereda una clase llamada `DispositivoConPantalla` que tiene un atributo (tamaño de pantalla) y a su vez de esta heredan otras dos clases: `Monitor` y `TV`. `TV` tiene como atributo una variable que indica si es inteligente o no mientras `Monitor` no contiene ningún atributo. ¿Estaría correcto modelar la clase `Monitor` que se mantiene vacía (sin atributos o métodos propios) o sustituir `DispositivoConPantalla` por esta (`Monitor`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sintácticamente es correcto.

Semánticamente hablando si puedes encontrarle un buen uso a ese diseño no veo porque no pueda ser totalmente válido.

Un ejemplo que se me ocurre:

Si  `DispositivoConPantalla` se declara como `abstract` y necesitas instancias de ésta que no sean `TV` en este caso la clase `Monitor` vacía sin otros miembros adicionales es la única solución para poder completar la jerarquía. Básicamente en este caso un nombre estilo `NoTV` tendría mas sentido ya que es la negación de la otra clase.

Por otro lado si realmente no tienes una buena justificación de la existencia de la clase `Monitor` probablemente será mejor que la elimines y trabajes directamente con `DispositivoConPantalla` para simplificar el diseño.